# mime type for cmpressed file upload like zip, rar?

Tags: php, upload

i want mime types for cmpressed file like zip file and rar file i searched before and find these mime types

```
application/zip',
'application/octet-stream',
'application/x-rar-compressed',
'application/octet-stream'
```

i think it's true but now i understand it's allow .php file or .bat file too, whats the wright mime for my goal?

EDIT: I want prevent uploading .php or .bat file, just allow compressed file

```
 protected function checkType($filename, $type) {
if (empty($type)) {
  return false;
} elseif (!in_array($type, $this->_permitted)) {
  $this->_badMessages[] = "file type not allowed $filename ";
  return false;
} else {
  return true;
}
```

}

Comment: So you'd like to allow PHP files and BAT files too?

Comment: @JamieBicknell No i wouldn't infact. how prevent them?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the PHP and BAT mime types to your `$this->_permitted` array like so:

```
$this->_permitted = array(
    'application/zi',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'application/x-rar-compressed',
    'application/octet-stream',
    'application/bat',
    'application/x-bat',
    'application/php',
    'application/x-php',
    'text/php',
    'text/x-php');
```

Comment: i dont want allow them! how block them i mean?